# FPDF: Multicell occupying the 2nd row

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to use the fpdf to wrap the text on the cells for my pdf.
Now I followed the tutorial in youtube and I tried many times to troubleshoot but I'm not sure why it occupies the 2nd row.
Reference link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utjJe90MeEw

Here's the code:

```
$details="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";

$result="It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.";

$interpretation="Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.";

$remarks="Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.";

$pdf->Ln(8);
$pdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 11);
$pdf->SetTextColor(39,39,39);
$pdf->Cell(185,10,'LABORATORY TEST RESULTS',0,1,'C');

$data=array(
    array(
        "Laboratory Test Performed:",
        $details
    ),
    array(
        "Test Result:",
        $result
    ),
    array(
        "Interpretation:",
        $interpretation
    ),
    array(
        "Remarks:",
        $remarks
    ),
);

//Laboratory Results
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $cellWidth=125; //wrapped cell width
    $cellHeight=6; //normal one-line cell height

    //check whether the text is overflowing
    if($pdf->GetStringWidth($item[1])<$cellWidth)
    {
        $line=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $textLength=strlen($item[1]); //total text length
        $errMargin=10; //cell width error margin, just in case
        $startChar=0; //character start position for each line
        $maxChar=0; //maximum character in a line, to be incremented later
        $textArray=array(); //to hold the strings for each line
        $tmpString=""; // to hold the string

        while($startChar<$textLength)
        {
            while($pdf->GetStringWidth($tmpString)<($cellWidth-$errMargin) &&
                ($startChar+$maxChar)<$textLength)
            {
                $maxChar++;
                $tmpString=substr($item[1], $startChar,$maxChar);
            }
            $startChar=$startChar+$maxChar;
            array_push($textArray,$tmpString);

            $maxChar=0;
            $tmpString='';
        }
        
        $line=count($textArray);
    }

    $pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 10);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(52,52,53);
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(131,131,133);
    $pdf->Cell(65,($line*$cellHeight),$item[0],1,0);
    $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
    $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 10);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(52,52,53);
    $pdf->Multicell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,$item[1],1);
}
```

I don't understand why this happens. The 1st cell of the first row is trying to occupy the 2nd row and there's this line on the 2nd row. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) may help.

Comment: @Olivier is there anyway to center the content of the 1st cell like showing in the picture?